# togggle menu need to open on click and close itself when click the other menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can make it make 
1- open toggle menu when on click menu (not opened by default)
2- close itself - if click other parent menu
trying to make it work for the project

and i copied from cssdesk

```js
$('.inbox li').click(function(e) {
    $('.inbox li.active').removeClass('active');
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
        $this.addClass('active');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.tree-toggler').click(function () {
  $(this).parent().children('ul.tree').toggle(300);
});
});
```

```html
 <link class="cssdeck" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" class="cssdeck">

<ul class="inbox-nav nav" style="border-top: 1px solid #eef1f5; margin-top:10px;" >
     <li class="">
      <a href="javascript:;" id="fldr3">menu 1
     </li>
     <li class="">
      <a data-title="Inbox" data-type="important" href="javascript:;">2nd Menu</a>
     </li>
     <li class="">
      <a data-title="Sent" data-type="sent" href="javascript:;">menu2</a>
     </li>
     <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="active tree-toggler">
                      <a href="javascript:;" id="fldr2">Toggle menu</a></li>
                        <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                         <li class=""><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                         <li class=""><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                       </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
<script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If user click is not neccesary you can do it by CSS, this is an example the 4th menu item has sub menu items

```css
.menu,
.menu-item {
  display: inline;
  cursor: default;
}
.menu-item.has-subItem {
  position: absolute;
}
.menu-item ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu-item:hover ul {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul class='menu'>
  <li class='menu-item'>Item 1</li>

  <li class='menu-item'>Item 2</li>

  <li class='menu-item'>Item 3</li>

  <li class='menu-item has-subItem'>Item 4
    <ul>
      <li class='sub-item'>sub 1</li>
      <li class='sub-item'>sub 2</li>
      <li class='sub-item'>sub 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have added collapse and its works perfectly
` <ul class="nav nav-list tree collapse">`

Answer (score 0):

In your `$('.inbox li').click()` function use jquery's [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) function on the `ul.tree` element. Since `.hide()` won't do anything if the element is already hidden, you don't need to check if it needs to be hidden.

(Similarly, you can pull the `$this.addClass('active');` statement out of the `if`, since it simply won't do anything if the class is already added!)

Comment: Oh, and add `style="display:none;"` to the html of the `ul.tree` element to have it hidden by default (sorry, missed that part of the question the first time through).